# apiUser.json in _http.get() is not found

Tags: json, angular, service

Indeed, I don't know why my url in _http.get('app/api/apiUsers') is not found while in a angular version 2.3.1 is functional but in angular version 4.0.0 it does not work.

This is my code and they are the same in both angular versions:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()

export class LoginService {
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getFromApiLogin(){

        console.log("I am here");

         return this._http.get('app/api/apiUsers.json)
            .do(x => console.log(x))
            .map(res => res.json());
   }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify, what do you mean when you say 'it's not found'?

Comment: keep .json file under assets :p

Comment: thanks :) @ Parth Ghiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using a CLI project... so it does just serve paths that you have added to the assets in the file .angular.cli.json

Try that:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "./app/api/apiUsers.json"
  ]
```

Comment: thanks @Ludwig, it's work. :). But, I have to do that each time I create a file like that ?

Comment: Yes. But like the other comment mentioned just put your json files into the assets folder. Might be a good idea to have all .json files in a central place. So the 'assets' entry makes everything in the '/assets' folder available.